# Ошибка при проверке Битрикс полный доступ?

Tags: битрикс

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня на локальной машине стоит Битрикс пакет Старт, при проверке полный доступ выдает ошибку, можно посмотреть на скриншоте. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой ошибкой ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Почему это ошибка возникла у меня? Потому что нашел эти файлы они находятся в папке Bitrix -> php_interface 3 файла, зашел свойства файла, там была галочка ТОЛЬКО ЧТЕНИЕ, убрал все заработало, т.е ошибка исчезла. У меня Windows 7 Professional 64 bit